# Connecting to multiple sortable items

Tags: jquery

I'm connecting to a sortable item :

```
$(function() {
    $('.page').sortable({
        connectWith: ".connect",
        items: ".myItems" 
    })
```

How do I connect to multiple items? something like :

```
$(function() {
    $('.page').sortable({
        connectWith: ".connect",
        items: [".myItems"] , [".myItems1"] 
    })
```

Comment: You can use `items: ".myItems,.myItems1"`

Comment: @Joy put into answer and ill accept!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the doc of [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/) specifies the `items` options takes a valid jQuery selector. So you can use it like

```
$(function() {
   $('.page').sortable({
     connectWith: ".connect",
     items: ".myItems,.myItesm1" 
  });
)};
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/UAcC7/47/)

In the fiddle you will find that You can only sort elements which have class of `fixed` and `me`.

Comment: you've error in your code. `.myItems,myItesm1` should `.myItems, .myItesm1`, missed a dot(`.`).